# Assets/App.js does not exist, but is stated in index.html and needed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am kind of new to reactJS and started to build my first webapp with react via yeoman and webpack-dev. Everything works fine but there is a strange thing. In the body of the `index.html` is following line:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/app.js"></script>`
The strange thing now is, there is of course a folder assets, but it has no app.js. So the only files I work with are the **run.js**, where I do all my Javascript stuff and requests and the **Main.js**, where I build my html stuff. So additionally there is the **server.js** which I start with `node server.js`:

```
 require('core-js/fn/object/assign'); var webpack = require('webpack'); var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server'); var config = require('./webpack.config'); var open = require('open');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), config.devServer) .listen(config.port, 'localhost', function(err) {   if (err) {
    console.log(err);   }   console.log('Listening at localhost:' + config.port);   console.log('Opening your system browser...');  open('http://localhost:' + config.port + '/webpack-dev-server/');

});
```

So I really have no idea where this app.js file is created and why I cannot use in the index.js for example the run.js file.

Please inform me, which files you need to see additionally, so I can provide the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that's created in memory if you have not yet run the `build`. Check your `webpack.config` file and check the `output`. It should contain `filename: app.js`, and `publicPath: /assets`.

Comment: So this is my webpack.config file: http://pastebin.com/uzNLpgup

I can't see where there is anything with output? Maybe you know more.

Comment: check the `cfg` folder and check the `base` and `dev` files.

Comment: Thanks!!! Found it, there is something in the base file. So now, I have a second question, I run this whole application as it is on a private server & access it via the url + port. So know it says, that it cannot find this app.js. Why is this & do you know a possibility to fix this?

Comment: if you're running it on a separate server, try serving the production files. in your `package.json` check the `script` part. it may be `npm run build` or npm run dist` depending on the settings. It will then build all the files and place it in a `build` folder. use those files for your private server